# robot framework: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, robotframework, fitnesse

I'm trying to get my first robot test running, but whatever I try, I get the following exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException
```

My test looks like

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  A resource file containing the application specific keywords
Library     Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Check out www google dot com
    Open Browser  https://www.google.com  htmlunit
    Close Browser
```

[image]

Im using the following versions:

```
    <version.robot>3.0.2</version.robot>
    <version.robot.maven.plugin>1.4.7</version.robot.maven.plugin>
    <version.selenium2library>1.4.0.8</version.selenium2library>
```

It's caused by something in the following jar.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
            <version>${version.selenium2library}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

When I add this dependency also  fitnesse test (whithout this jar it's working) gives the same exception.

Comment: Have you included the [HTMLUnitDriver class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/htmlunit-driver)?

Comment: In the same project I have a cucumber test which also uses HTMLUnit so it is there.

Comment: @A.Kootstra I've added some info the the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used Fitnesse, Cumber and Robot Framework in 1 maven module. It's for a demo application to show how these framworks can fit in our jenkins 2 pipeline. Fitnesse and Cucumber were using Selenium 3 and  `robotframework-selenium2library-java` doesnt seem to work with a Selenium 3. So there are conflicts.

To solve this I put every test framework in a seperate maven module wich will fix the problem. Also gives this me more flexibility with the selenium versions in the future.